# jQuery form onchange and submit

Tags: jquery

I would like to make an ajax call on a form only when a user changes a input value or hits enter in an input value.

The problem I have is that hitting enter in an input submits the form which makes an ajax call and also the onchange event occurs and triggers the ajax call.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).on 'change', '.painter-edit :input', ->
    $(this).closest('form').submit()
```

Is it possible to have both input change and submit trigger submit?

Comment: You want to catch the `keydown` event for enter and change it there.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the Event thrown by the return key and add your own functionality:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault(); //this prevents your submit
      //make your ajax call here 
      return false;
    }
  });
```

For onchange you could do it with jquery selector :input like this:

```
$(':input').on('change', function(){
    //make your ajax call here 
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq6GF/)

Comment: This will also listen for change?

Comment: No, the change event you need in addition, i would attach it to every input field.

Comment: I added a proposal for the change event, you could also use jQuery trigger function in keydown event to call the onchange event

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to capture the `keypress` event, determine if it's character 13 ("enter"), and then execute the ajax call.

If you are executing the same ajax for both, then you should abstract the ajax call away in a function, and then call the function from both this code, and the onchange code you have already.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // call the ajax function
  }
});
```